# Get Active Form in FireMonkey Android Application

Tags: delphi, dynamic, user-controls, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm stuck. How to get an active form in FireMonkey Android application? 
I have only a `TComponent` placed on this form, but it seems like it doesn't contain a reference to the root element.

I dynamically create a control (`TToolBar`) and want to add it to the top of the active form, when component is placed on it. The problem is:

```delphi
  ToolBar := TToolBar.Create(Application);
  ToolBar.Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
  ToolBar.Parent := ?;  // I don't know what parent to specify for this control
```

May be I should instantiate a new form and place the control on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The right solution:

   ```
   ToolBar.Parent := Application.MainForm;
   ```

   ([docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Forms.TApplication.MainForm))
2. This will work, but you will be unable to add childrens to the `ToolBar`:

   ```
   if Application.HasParent then

     ToolBar.Parent := Application.GetParentComponent as TFmxObject;
   ```

   ([docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TComponent.GetParentComponent))
3. This internal function should also do the trick in case if you know [`FormFamily`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.FormFamily):

   `function Application.GetDeviceForm(const FormFamily: string): TCommonCustomForm; overload;`